# C++. Чем заменить тип huge компилятора Turbo C в GCC MinGW?

Tags: c, mingw, borland, типы

Есть кусочек кода программы компилируемой в *Borland Turbo C*.
Там есть такое объявление:

```
huge x[240001];
```

При попытке скомпилировать эту строку компилятором GCC (MinGW32) происходит ошибка:

> huge does not name a type.

Соответственно вопросы:

1) Что за тип такой `huge`? Каков `sizeof()` в байтах?

2) Это структура или что?

3) Где объявлен этот тип? В каких заголовочных файлах?

4) Чем его можно заменить в GCC (MinGW32)?

P.S. Желательно точное соответствие замены, т.к. важен размер, порядок байт при считывании/записи массива `x[240001]`, 10 байт пишется в файл `fwrite(x,10,240000,ou);`.

Comment: Если прога компилируется в Turbo C, то на первые три вопроса Вы можете ответить сами.

Comment: @alexolut, при условии, что у него есть компилятор Turbo C ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну он же как-то узнал, что она компилируется. Логично предположить, что путём компиляции. :)

Comment: @alexolut, "компилируемой" != "компилирующейся". Т. е. я так понял, что она написана под Turbo C и должна в нём компилироваться, но он этого проверить не может и переписывает её под mingw.

Comment: `fwrite(x,10,240000,ou)` - никак не может означать запись 10 байт в файл.

Comment: @Qwertiy не вижу никакой разницы в данном контексте.

Comment: @AnT макроподстановка может творить [чудеса](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eXuRJUVD58LcaVGD). Хотя и не уверен, что тут нет какого-нибудь UB.

Comment: @alexolut: Макроподстановки могут много чего творить, в т.ч. превратить `huge` в `enum { A, B, C }`, а `x` в `(*fun)`. Но Бритва Оккама и здравый смысл исключают необоснованное рассмотрение макроподстановок.

Answer (score 5):

О какой версии компилятора идет речь? Просто начиная с версии 3.0 компилятор назывался просто Borland C++, без Turbo. Так что я вынужден считать, что речь идет о Turbo C 2.0. Тогда...

Тогда это были 16-разрядные программы, которые работали в DOS в реальном режиме работы процессора, так что указатели там состояли из сегмента и смещения... Вобщем, рассказывать долго, почитайте лучше сами - например, [тут](http://proguroki.ru/urok7/urok7_1/urok7_1_2/urok-7-1-2-ukazateli-i-modeli-pamyati) или [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8_Intel_x86) или где-нибудь еще.

Соответственно, у вас просто выделен массив памяти с использованием такого указателя памяти, ну, а пропущенный тип в C всегда воспринимался как `int`.
Так что это должен быть просто `int x[240001];`.

Только учтите, что `int` тогда представлял собой 16-битное значение.

Что до `fwrite` - то в приведенной у вас записи в файл пишется 240000 раз по 10 байт. Это смущает, потому что такой памяти под DOS просто не было - вся она была ограничена 640КБайтами. Так что, может, поделитесь исходником - выложив его где-то? Просто интересно посмотреть и разобраться, что же это такое программа пытается сделать.

*"По-моему, так"* (с) Пух

Comment: В таком случае fwrite не сочетается с объявлением массива.

Comment: @Qwertiy: То, что в вопросе написано про `fwrite` - бессмыслица, которая не сочетается вообще ни с чем.

Comment: @Qwertiy Там вообще хотят записывать непонятное, потому я и попросил дать исходники. Не верится мне в него вовсе...

Comment: В Turbo C 2.0, насколько я помню, не было возможности указывать `huge` в объявлениях массивов. `huge` был спецификатором, употребимым только с указателями, а большие массивы требовалось аллоцировать динамически. Возможность объявить именованный `huge` массив - существенно более поздняя фича борландовского компилятора.

Comment: @AnT  Мое **"По-моему, так"** *(с) Пух* я употребляю там, где работаю по памяти и не уверен на 200%. Все же это было более 25 лет тому - могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @AnT, я только в borland c++ писал, но huge вообще не помню. Вот дальние указатели были, то там было `far` (и необязательный `near`), и пачка функций `farmalloc`, `farfree` и подобных. А в каком контексте `huge`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: `far` позволял вам адресовать всю память, но не позволял создавать/адресовать непрерывные объекты (в частности массивы) размером больше одного сегмента. Так было потому, что при работе через `far` указатель сегментная часть указателя при выполнении адресной арифметики всегда оставалась неизменной, менялось только 16-битное смещение. `huge` указатель по представлению не отличается от `far`, но при работе с `huge` указателем при необходимости первычисляется как смещение, так и сегмент.

Comment: При этом по умолчанию любая модификация `huge` указателя сразу же вызывала автоматическую его нормализацию: т.е. перевычисление сегмента и смещения так, чтобы смещение было < 16. Такой `huge` указатель, за счет постоянной нормализации, может спокойно "гулять" по всей памяти. За это приходится платить накладными расходами на постоянное поддержание `huge` указателя в нормализованном виде. Была также опция, которая говорила, что нормализовать `huge` указатель надо не постоянно, а только когда он приближается к границе сегмента. Это было чуть эффективнее, но с рядом подводных камней.